# Can't get a DIV to float above a DIV with image in it

Tags: css, html

Here are links to the syntax for the index page and the related CSS sheet. (Used pastebin) I am trying to get "InfoBox" to float above the main header image but instead it just pushes the image down. I have tried using z-indexes and adjusting position but I can't get it to work. If anyone has any ideas please let me know. Thanks :)

HTML Code: http://pastebin.com/WZ0zY8GD
CSS Code: http://pastebin.com/3atWdyEV

Comment: 1) Do you mean `.infoBlock` and not `.infoBox`?  I do not see an `.infoBox`.  2) `.infoBlock` is above the header image.  Did you mean **overlay** the header image?

Comment: Should the `logo.png` be directly to the left of `.infoBlock`?  Meaning the "same row?"

Answer (score 0):

the Infoblock has a lot of height to it.  Get rid of that line or set it to have less height.  Also, get rid of margin-left: auto; since that doesn't really make sense.  It just pushes infoblock all the way to the right.

Comment: `margin-left: auto;` makes perfect sense if he wants it on the right and doesn't need anything to the left of it.

Comment: He wants it to float above the image though and the image is on the left.

Comment: Not in Chrome or FF.  `.infoBlock` is above `<img src="images\logo.png" />`.  Like I said in my comment, does _float above_ = _overlay_?  That is not clearly defined by the OP.